# How to get a bar with colors on top of a plot?

Tags: r, plot

I have an R plot with lines. Each sections belong to a category defined by p. I tried coloring the plot with rectangles, but the results is messy. Instead of getting rectangles amid the plot then, I would like to get a thin bar on top. Is it possible to do this in R without messing the other features of the plot?

```
v <- c(7,12,28,3,41)
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <- c(1,2,5,6,7)
p <- c(1,2,1,1,2)
data <- data.frame(v,x,y,p)

par(mar=c(5,5,2,5))
with(data, plot(v, type="l",col="black",ylab="scale_1"))
par(new=T)
with(data, plot(y, type="l", axes=F, xlab=NA, ylab=NA,col="blue"))
par(new=T)
axis(side=4)
mtext(side=4,line=3, 'scale_2' )
rect(data$x-0.5,min(data$y),data$x+0.5,max(data$y),col=adjustcolor(data$p,alpha=0.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to set the y-coordinate for the bottom of the plot:

```
rect(data$x-0.5, 
     max(data$y) - 1,  # New bottom coordinate
     data$x+0.5,
     max(data$y),
     col=adjustcolor(data$p,alpha=0.5))
```

Output:

[image]

Or if you want the rectangles fully separated from the lines:

```
rect(data$x-0.5, 
     max(data$y),
     data$x+0.5,
     max(data$y) + 1,
     col=adjustcolor(data$p,alpha=0.5))
```